# QML list of images not visible

Tags: qt, list, qml, qt5

I have not worked with `QML` lists much, but  I have a `QML` parent `Item` that needs to draw a list of little tile images.

Whenever a `QML` `Image` is taken out of the list it is viewable but not while in the list. 
(No compile-time or runtime warning or errors in either case)

Displays okay:

```
Item {
    id : player_health

    Image {
        z:2;
        height: 26;
        width: 19;
        x: 50;
        y: 50;
        source:"resources/gameplay/square_pink.png"
    }
}
```

Does not display (neither of these images):

```
Item {
    id : player_health

    property list<Image> bars: [
        Image { z:2; height: 26; width: 19; x: 50; y:50; source: "resources/gameplay/square_pink.png"},
        Image { z:2; height: 26; width: 19; x: 50; y:50; source: "resources/gameplay/square_blue.png"}
    ]
}
```

I would like the images in the list to be visible but can't find a way to do it via a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want beautiful place your pictures, then you can use simple positioner `Row` or `Column`. For example:

```
Rectangle {
    x: 8
    y: 250
    width: 320; height: 110
    color: "black"



    Row {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        spacing: 5

        Image { width: 100; height: 100; source: "images/earth.png" }
        Image { width: 100; height: 100; source: "images/uranus.png" }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Your solution is close to what I need since I'll be using regular spacing. However I think a Grid with a Repeater is closer to what I need (possibly need to go vertically and horisontally together / diagonally).

Answer (score 1):

```
Item {
   id : player_health

   Grid {

     rows: 5; columns: 1; spacing: 10

     Repeater { model: 5
                Image { z:2; height: 26; width: 19; x: 50; y:50; source:"resources/gameplay/square_pink.png" }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you created is a property list with `Image` types. Since this is only a `property` it won't be shown unless you create them.

One way would be to contain them in `Components` within the `list` and a [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) would be able to create them. But I guess that wasn't your intention based on the recent answers.